# Tableau: A bar which shows the difference between

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following data for which i need to create a bar chart as shown in the picture in tableau:

[image]

```
Brand   Sales   week
A   12  1
B   20  1
C   14  1
A   12  2
B   22  2
C   16  2
A   18  3
B   16  3
C   27  3
```

My chart must contain sales in rows and week in columns. For every week, I must show three bars:

- 1. Sales for Brand A (A is always fixed)
- 2. sales for Brand B/ Brand C (B/C:- Its a parameter selection)
- 3. Difference between sales of these two

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this what you asking for   ??

Comment: How does that give the difference between the sales? You are just summing the sales and breaking them out by week and brand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating calculated fields of the sales for `Brand A`, `Brand B/C` (based on selection), and the difference between those two calculated fields:

- Brand A Sales: `SUM(IF [Brand] = 'A' THEN [Sales] END)`
- Brand B/C Sales: `SUM(IF [Brand] != 'A' THEN [Sales] END)`
- Brand Difference: `[Brand A Sales] - [Brand B/C Sales]`

The calculation is dependent on your filter being setup properly, so make sure you have something like this calculated field in your filter card and set to `True`:

- Brand Filter: `[Brand Select] = [Brand] OR [Brand] = 'A'` *[Brand Select] is the parameter to select between B or C*

Lastly, place `[Measure Names]` in the columns section and `[Measure Values]` in the rows section. Be sure only to include the 3 calculated fields mentioned above.

You should get a result like so:
*Brand B* -

[image]

*Brand C* -

[image]

> Note: The calculation for the difference between brands may need to be altered based on your expected output. I based mine in the example off of what I assumed you had within the image in your post.